# We Couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again (PowerBI)

Tags: powerbi, odata, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, cds

While reading data from OData in PowerBI I am getting error

> We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again.

API link is generated from SAP (cloud) CDS view and that link is fed to OData in Power BI Desktop but it is not able to authenticate it. However same link is opening in web browser without any issue.

Expecting to read SAP CDS view data in Power BI.